# Can anyone recommend an affordable IPSec appliance that is compatible with Windows 7's built-in client?

Tags: windows-7, vpn, ipsec

I am looking for an affordable IPSec appliance that will work with the built-in client in Windows 7.

Comment: Do you mean the DirectAccess client in Win7?

Comment: @Chris - I'm not familiar with DirectAccess, but that appears to be something else. I'm talking about the VPN connection you can add in Windows without having to install separate client software.

Comment: I think you're looking at PPTP/L2TP connections. What are you trying to accomplish? Do you want a VPN appliance at an office (or at home) that you can dial back to?

Comment: @Chris - I want an appliance at the office that remote users can connect to without having to install special software. We actually have a Netgear FVS338 for IPSec now, but they don't have a Win7 64-bit client yet - which is a problem for us.

Answer (score 0):

Juniper SSG range.

Comment: Intriguing.  Do you have a cookbook for setting up SSG firewalls for use with Windows 7 VPN clients?  Because Juniper wants to sell you their VPN Client license for $10/each, and at this price it isn't cost-effective to fiddle with it trying to make it work (the problem we had back in XP days).

Comment: This Juniper KB article may have some insight into the requirements for Windows 7 and L2TP to an SSG firewall:
http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB16075

Answer (score 0):

[Sonicwall](http://www.mines.edu/~gmurray/HowTo/sshNotes.html) and [Cisco PIX](http://www.cisco.com/go/pix) devices will do what you want (If I'm understanding the question correctly); but are not cheap. If you have a linux box at the site running [PopTop](http://www.poptop.org/) or similar software would work too.

Answer (score 0):

The Win7 IPSec implementation uses IKEv2.  I know Sonicwall supports this. You may want to contact them and see if they support the Win7 client.

Answer (score -1):

Cisco Asa 5500 series with 8.4(2) firmware supports ikev2.  Should be possible to get that going.  Asa 5505 and 5510 is very popular in smb and mid sized companies.